# (iphone) can i give different intervals between images when animating?

Tags: iphone, animation, intervals

I'm animating several image as follows.

```
     UIImageView* animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: self.animationViewContainer.bounds];
    animationView.animationImages = animationArray;
    animationView.animationDuration = 0.5;
    animationView.animationRepeatCount = 5;
    [animationView startAnimating];
```

What I'd like to do is, controlling duration between animationImages.
For instance, show image1 for 0.3 sec image2 for 0.5 sec..

There must be some way to do this, but hard to find an answer.
I've asked the same question here before, but wording of the question wasn't so clear.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set one image more then one time, for example set the interval to 0.3 sec and display one twice to get 0.6 seconds.

Comment: yeah, that's doable, it will be very hard to do 0.3sec 0.5sec where one is not multiple of another. was hoping there is a more convenient way. Thanks though

Comment: you can use 0.1 second and take the first three times and the second fife times. It wouldn't look elegant but you would have 0.3 and 0.5 second